# CakePhp - Dropdown lists - calling association find('list') for every action?

Tags: php, cakephp, model

Lets say I have a Company model and Companies controller.  Foreign keys in the company table include `time_zone_id`, `station_id`, `state_id`, `city_id`.

I had actions in the CompaniesController to add, edit, view Companies.  For adding and editing, I need dropdown lists of all the foreign key associations (time zones, states, cities, stations).  So in those actions, I find myself writing lots of the following for each action:

```
$this->set('cities', $this->Station->City->find('list'));
$this->set('states', $this->Station->State->find('list'));
```

etc...

Seems like a lot of code repetition.  Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a pre-view callback such as afterFilter to your Companies controller:

```
function afterFilter() {
    // conditional ensures only actions that need the vars will receive them
    if (in_array($this->action, array('index', 'view', 'edit'))) {
        $this->set('cities', $this->Station->City->find('list'));
        $this->set('states', $this->Station->State->find('list'));
    }
}
```

afterFilter will be called after every Companies controller action.

Comment: Actually just tried this, it didn't work.  But it did work with beforeFilter().  Is that what you meant, or am I missing something?

Comment: I wrote `afterFilter` as that's one I thought of at the time but I really meant to try any of the pre-view callbacks. My main intent was to let you know that there are powerful callbacks that can help with this type of issue. I'm glad `beforeFilter` works for you!

Comment: afterFilter is called after all is done, basically just before __destruct(). beforeRender() is what you want. http://book.cakephp.org/view/984/Callbacks

Comment: @dogmatic69: It's my understanding the beforeRender is called after the view class has been loaded and variables imported, so `$this->set` won't work (although there's another way to access them).

Comment: you are wrong. you can call $this->set() in views and elements

Answer (score 0):

Filters are good, as in webbiedave's answer, but it might get complicated if you end up with a lot of conditional logic.

Another option is that you can define methods in a controller than aren't intended as actions/views: it's a normal PHP object afterall. Better yet, if using PHP5, you can declare these methods private to ensure they cannot be mistaken for actions...

For example, you could define the following in your controller:

```
private function _populate_dropdowns() {
    $this->set('cities', $this->Station->City->find('list'));
    $this->set('states', $this->Station->State->find('list'));
}
```

Then call it at the start of any action that needs it:

```
public function add() {
    $this->_populate_dropdowns();
    // ... 
    // add code
}

public function edit() {
    $this->_populate_dropdowns();
    // ... 
    // edit code
}
```

Comment: Yeah I thought about this.  And then considered combining the 2 ideas:  creating private methods, but calling them from beforeFilter()

Comment: That works too. :) Is simply comes down to how often the code is needed. beforeFilter runs with every request, so if you think most requests need it, it seems appropriate.